# Cannot send the emails through the ASP Form

Tags: forms, email, asp-classic

I am unable to send the email through the form because of the following error. I assume that the form doesn't work because of the depricated CDO? I'm not sure, but also I am not sure how to fix this problem.

```
CDO.Message.1 error '80040220'

The "SendUsing" configuration value is invalid.

/thankyou.asp, line 24
```

The Code

```vb
<%
Set objMail = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Message")

objMail.Configuration.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2 
objMail.Configuration.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "localhost"
objMail.Configuration.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
objMail.Configuration.Fields.Update

objMail.From = Request.Form("Email") ' change this to an email address
objMail.To = "admin@domain.com" ' change this to your email address
objMail.Subject = "name Questions/Comments" ' change this to your subject
'Set the e-mail body format (HTMLBody=HTML TextBody=Plain) 

'Set the e-mail body format (HTMLBody=HTML TextBody=Plain) 
objMail.HTMLBody = "<font size=3 face=verdana>"
objMail.HTMLBody = objMail.HTMLBody & "<strong>" & "From: " & "</strong>" & Request.form("Name") & "<br>"
objMail.HTMLBody = objMail.HTMLBody & "<strong>" & "Email: " & "</strong>" & Request.Form("Email") & "<br>"
objMail.HTMLBody = objMail.HTMLBody & "<strong>" & "Phone: " & "</strong>" & Request.Form("Phone") & "<br>" & "<br>"
objMail.HTMLBody = objMail.HTMLBody & "<strong>" & "Questions/Comments: " & "</strong>" & "<br>" & Replace(Request.Form("Details"), vbCrLf, "<br />") & "<br>" & "<br>" & "</font>"
'objMail.HTMLBody = objMail.HTMLBody & "<em>" & "Sent at " & Now() & "</em>" & "</font>"

objMail.Send()

Set objMail = Nothing*

%>
```

I don't have the access to the physical server and I cannot change the permissions myself.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/akashb/archive/2010/05/24/error-cdo-message-1-0x80040220-the-quot-sendusing-quot-configuration-value-is-invalid-on-iis-7-5.aspx

Any ideas how can I fix this piece of code to make it work again?

I have tried this: http://forums.iis.net/t/1146477.aspx?The+SendUsing+configuration+value+is+invalid+

Changing SendUsing to 1.

And setting up google snmp to send the emails without much results. Any information would be helpful.

Comment: look at this posting I think you are missing one configuration.Fields http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms873037%28EXCHG.65%29.aspx

Comment: DJ, I get the same error with field "objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25"

Comment: If you're using a gmail smtp server then you should use port 587 rather than 25  You'll also need username and password in your config fields  http://www.paulsadowski.com/wsh/cdo.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace your code with this:

```
<%
Set cdoConfiguration = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Configuration") 

With cdoConfiguration 
  .Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "localhost" 
  .Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25 
  .Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2 
  .Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60 
  .Fields.Update 
End With 

Dim tmpStr
tmpStr = ""

tmpStr = "<font size=""3"" face=""verdana"">"
tmpStr = tmpStr & "<ul>"
tmpStr = tmpStr & "<li><strong>" & "From: " & "</strong>: " & Request.form("Name") & "</li>"
tmpStr = tmpStr & "<li><strong>" & "Email: " & "</strong>: " & Request.form("Email") & "</li>"
tmpStr = tmpStr & "<li><strong>" & "Phone: " & "</strong>: " & Request.form("Phone") & "</li>"
tmpStr = tmpStr & "<li><strong>Questions/Comments</strong>:<br/>"
tmpStr = tmpStr & Replace(Request.Form("Details"), vbCrLf, "<br />")
tmpStr = tmpStr & "</li>"
tmpStr = tmpStr & "</ul>"
tmpStr = tmpStr & "<p>Sent at " & Now() & "</p>"
tmpStr = tmpStr & "</font>"

Set newMailObj           = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Message") 
newMailObj.Configuration = cdoConfiguration 
newMailObj.Subject       = "name Questions/Comments" 
newMailObj.From          = Request.Form("Email")
newMailObj.To            = "admin@domain.com" 
newMailObj.HTMLBody      = tmpStr 

newMailObj.Send 

set newMailObj = nothing     
set cdoConfiguration = nothing
%>
```

and let us know if it works like that, cause if it does, your code (or at least the part you paste to us) is not correct...

and, by the way, if you're using `localhost` I'm almost sure that the server configuration is not necessary... It is obligatory if you use a remote server like `smtp.server.com`

Comment: I just called customer support to see whether we can use localhost at all, and they gave me gateway to our Out smtp, but still yet got it working.

Comment: so, is it working now or not, if not, with this code I pasted as well still does not work? Then you should request an example from your hosting, as they ALWAYS have those in their FAQ's... might be a special configuration.

Comment: I will tomorrow. I was told that it might take time for configurations they did to take effect. I'll be looking into this tomorrow in the morning. Thanks.

Comment: It worked, thank you. I had to spend hour and a half with customer service to also find out that we had 2 FTP accounts. The one I had was not the right one, even though the content was the same... Thank you so much!